# How to get the real coordinates from the image coordinates?

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, cmvision, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello dear friends,

I want to calibrate an colored object, so with CMVISION I achieved to calibrate and it gives me the coordinate in the Image, but for calibration I need the Real coordinate, I know that in some how I could use PCL (point cloud library) to get them but I dont know how,

I am new in PCL , so any body can give me a hint to start?, (I am searching in parallel too)

Thank you in advance
PS : I am using a Kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131291/how-to-get-the-real-coordinates-from-the-image-coordinates?/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on 2014-08-12**:
can you have a look at this question and if u have an answer may be provide me with it? http://answers.ros.org/question/189846/working-with-cmvisionblobs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As an example, I have a node that receives a point cloud, extracts an image and runs a vision algorithm on it, and then retrieves the XYZ coordinates of the detected features:

https://github.com/trainman419/targeting/blob/master/target_detector/src/targets.cpp#L219-L269

The key things to pick out are the conversion from a structured point cloud to an image:

```
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr image = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::Image>();
pcl::toROSMsg( *cloud, *image );
```

And the return conversion from image coordinates to a 3D point from the cloud:

```
pcl::PointXYZ p1 = depth.at(x, y);
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-02-19**:
Thank you for your answer, I am trying to understand your code...

I appreciate your help

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-02-20**:
I just see your modification , thanks a lot dear ahendrix....
I appreciate your help

Hamed